# Copying users between AD-LDS (ADAMish) instances

Tags: active-directory, ldap, adam

I have set up an instance of AD-LDS as in here
http://www.thegeekispeak.com/archives/28
and connected to it with Softerra LDAP Browser

What I don't know how to do is get the users stored in the AD-LDS "database" on my colleague's machine into my machine. Is there some export/import process? Do I do it from the LDAP browser or somewhere else?

If someone has done this and can tell me how it could save me a lot of time and I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A good tool to work with directories in general is [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) and the language used to export/import datas from one Directory to another is LDIF. Apache Directory Studio log all your operation on a Directory in LDIF format.

Another is to build your version of AD-LDS as a replicate of the one of your colleague's machine.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to copy the entire object including attributes like SID and Password. If you simply want to share data, you can create replicas and the instances will be in sync.